# How to open large file with extension .v2.gz?

Tags: file-format, gzip

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have a large file with the extension .v2.gz and I cannot extract it with archive manager. Is there any way to uncompress the file using terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use `gunzip`:

```
gunzip file.v2.gz
```

The extracted file file will be `file.v2`.